# How to make a sprite jump using CCJumpTo in cocos2d-x

Tags: c++, xcode, cocos2d-x

I am new to cocos2d-x and I am developing a game in xcode using cocos2d-x 2.0.4. In that I want to make my sprite jump.So that i use the following code. Using that code it is working, but the problem is if i tab the screen continuously the sprite is keep on jumping(like flying). But i want my sprite should not jump until the first jump finished. Following is code,

```
void PlayScene::ccTouchesBegan(cocos2d::CCSet* pTouches, cocos2d::CCEvent* pEvent)
{
CCTouch* touch = (CCTouch* )pTouches->anyObject();
CCPoint location = touch->locationInView();
location = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->convertToGL(location);
 CCJumpTo *pJumpTo = new CCJumpTo();
pJumpTo->initWithDuration(1, ccp(winwsize/5.5,winhsize/2.2), 100, 1);
man->runAction(pJumpTo);
}
```

Please help me to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if there are any running actions on your `man` sprite. This can be done easily by calling `man->numberOfRunningActions()` - if this is not 0 you shouldn't start new action.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. In my game man sprite has running animation and while tab the screen it is jumping.While jumping time also the animation is running. So how can i make my sprite jump after the jump completes.

Comment: It is working now I just give the Man->numberOfRunningActions()==1 in if condition, and now it is working properly.

Comment: hmm ... listen @socrates   
i think you should have to assign every action a unique tag  
and after that you can check `man->getNumberOfRunningActionsByTag();`  
because some time while you set jump on single tap and you tap twice in this case sprite will jump twice   
this is a solution to keep this type of error.